# Fast algorithm for sum of absolute eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a non-selfadjoint real or complex $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$, is there a (faster) algorithm for computing 
$$\sum_i\lvert\lambda_i\rvert$$
which does not involve computing the individual eigenvalues?

Comment: do you know for selfadjoint?